# find control in listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, gridview, findcontrol

By pressing button in GridView i need to find control in Listview.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<td>

    <asp:Label ID="lblMarketLVBalanceHeader" runat="server" Text="Balance: "></asp:Label>
</td>


<td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMarketLVBalanceValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Money", "{0:####}$") %>'></asp:Label>

</td>

</ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void GVMarketItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
if (e.CommandName.Equals("Buy"))
        {  GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
         /*  string itemID = row.Cells[0].Text;
           string itemName = row.Cells[1].Text;
           string itemCostStr = row.Cells[3].Text; */
 string curBalanceStr = ((Label)LVMarketBalanceShow.FindControl("lblMarketLVBalanceValue")).Text;
}
```

Code seems find, but i have "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when i'm trying to Find control.

```
string curBalanceStr = ((Label)LVMarketBalanceShow.FindControl("lblMarketLVBalanceValue")).Text;
```

Did the same to DetailsView and it was Ok.. What's wrong with ListView?

**UPD: Trying to get first fow of listview**

```
ListViewDataItem curBalanceLV = LVMarketBalanceShow.Items[0];
       string curBalanceStr =((Label)curBalanceLV.FindControl("lblMarketLVBalanceValue")).Text;
```

But getting an error "Index was out of range."

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to find the control within the specific row.

```
string curBalanceStr = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblMarketLVBalanceValue")).Text
```

Answer (score 1):

> Did the same to DetailsView and it was Ok.. What's wrong with
>   ListView?

A DetailsView is used to tackle with one row at a time so you can directly call `FindControl()` on the detailsview but gridview and listview are meant to display multiple records and your markup you define inside  `<ItemTemplate />` is just a template for each row. You'll be able to find the controls that you define in the template inside of each row.

Comment: @RaShe it doesn't matter if it just displays single row. The control is meant for multiple rows. Consider a `List<String>`. Even if the list has just one string, you cannot do string operations on the list. You'll have to retrieve the one item first and then do whatever string operation on that item. If you are always going to have just one row then you should stick to DetailsView or retrieve the row and then try to acces the control.

Comment: I understand it.
Now I'm trying to get that row 
 ListViewDataItem curBalanceLV = LVMarketBalanceShow.Items[0];
           string curBalanceStr =((Label)curBalanceLV.FindControl("lblMarketLVBalanceValue")).Text;

But i have an error "Index was out of range".