# Listview notshowing up on the code behind file

Tags: asp.net

I created a list view and have a requirement to creater another list view inside the first listview.When i go to the code behind file i do not see the listview2 control which is the name of the second list view

What am i doing wrong?

**Below is my mark up code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Attestation2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Attestation2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="z-index: 1; left: 21px; top: 0px; position: absolute; height: 313px;
    width: 983px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Entitlementdlist" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Visible="true"
            ToolTip="All the Requests in this dropdown are Entitlement Requests only">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:ListView ID="listview1" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemplaceholder" >
            <LayoutTemplate>         
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemplaceholder" runat="server" />  
            </LayoutTemplate> 

            <ItemTemplate>
                <table style="border:1px solid black;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Report Name</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="ReportNameLbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("REPORT_DESCRIPTION.rptdesctext") %>' Width="500"></asp:TextBox> </td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Content Description</td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="ContentDescLbl" Text='<%#Eval("REPORT_REQUEST.StopLossMax") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                        </td>




                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                    <td>
                    Frequency
                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <asp:Label ID="frequencyLbl" Text='<%#Eval("REPORT_REQUEST.reportfrequency") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>


                    <td>
             <asp:ListView ID="listview2" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemplaceholder1" >
            <LayoutTemplate>         
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemplaceholder1" runat="server" />  
            </LayoutTemplate> 

            <ItemTemplate>

             <table style="border:1px solid black;">
                    <tr>

                        <td>Recepients</td>
                        <td>
                         <asp:Label ID="frequencyLbl" Text='<%#Eval("REPORTAlaska.reportfrequency") %>' runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
                    </td>

                    </tr>
                </table>


            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a control nested in a template, you need to use "FindControl" method.

**Edit:**

If you use a function, look at its description at MSDN, it will save you time spent waiting for an answer here :) In short, FindControl isn't a recursive function and if the control isn't directly in the collection of controls of the chosen element, it won't work. You're trying to access a ListView that is in another ListView, so you can't use Page.FindControl, but instead you can do something like this:

```
myListView.FindControl(...)
```

Hope you get the idea now and that it works for you.

Comment: I used thefind control method and now get error:object reference not set to an instance of an object.below is my code                                                        ListView listview_nested = Page.FindControl("listview2") as ListView; listview_nested.DataSource = RECEPIENTDATA; listview_nested.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

this is the normal behavior.your nested ListView is defined in template of outer ListView.
u must access nested listview with FindControl() method of specific row.

for example code check this : [Find Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341838/find-control-in-listview)